# How to form a tree map, to make so-slow-sql faster

Tags: sql, dictionary, sql-server-2012, tree

How to form a tree with sql.
I can't find good way to form a tree with sql as below.

1. tree is made of positions.
2. every position has 3 numbers.
    own number 
    up number
    sequence number
3. top position is only one.
4. every position has unique number.
5. every position links other position.
    from UP to DOWN with up number.

    e.g
    case of 4 positions tree

    00002 - own number
    00001 - up number
        1 - sequence number

    00003 - own number
    00001 - up number
        2 - sequence number

    00004 - own number
    00002 - up number
        1 - sequence number

         00001
     00002 00003
     00004
6. UP position is center of all DOWN position.
7. every position can have plural positions under it.
8. every position don't overlap others.
9. no gap.
10. position's 
      height - 80
      width - 80
     between positions - 20
11. top position
     x axis - 0
     y axis - 0

    we have 200,000 positions.
    although we'd like to form a tree within 30 seconds, our best record is 5 hours!

    would you help us? please.

    thank you so much.

    https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/FIkn7yIVKozIL9S5XZFyn_S0YL2NBnFf-9j4PwQOW7CjmTXXXvxpOG4OEUXlTPbm0Th7uTKsR7QxfjY=w1367-h727-rw

source code for sqlserver 2012

```
/* start */

IF object_id('WEBTreeMap') IS not NULL DROP TABLE WEBTreeMap;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WEBTreeMap](
    [IDNO] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [Eda] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [UPIDNO] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [UPEda] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [MapLimitLV_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MapLimitFG_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DownPossession] [bit] NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__WEBTreeMap__29A60B9828B2E0D5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDNO] ASC,
    [Eda] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
;

/* insert sample */
INSERT INTO WEBTreeMap 
SELECT '0000000001' as IDNO, '001' AS Eda, '' AS UPIDNO, '' AS UPEda, 0 AS MapLimitLV_1, 0 AS MapLimitFG_1, 'true'  AS DownPossession UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001' as IDNO, '002' AS Eda, '0000000001' AS UPIDNO, '001' AS UPEda, 0 AS MapLimitLV_1, 0 AS MapLimitFG_1, 'true' AS DownPossession UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001' as IDNO, '003' AS Eda, '0000000001' AS UPIDNO, '001' AS UPEda, 0 AS MapLimitLV_1, 0 AS MapLimitFG_1, 'true' AS DownPossession UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001' as IDNO, '004' AS Eda, '0000000001' AS UPIDNO, '002' AS UPEda, 0 AS MapLimitLV_1, 0 AS MapLimitFG_1, 'true' AS DownPossession UNION ALL
SELECT '0000000001' as IDNO, '005' AS Eda, '0000000001' AS UPIDNO, '003' AS UPEda, 0 AS MapLimitLV_1, 0 AS MapLimitFG_1, 'true' AS DownPossession
;

IF object_id('WEBTreeMap_2') IS not NULL DROP TABLE WEBTreeMap_2;
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WEBTreeMap_2](
    [TopIDNO] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TopEda] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [IDNO] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Eda] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Soshiki] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [LV] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MapLimitFG] [int] NOT NULL,
    [xaxis] [int] NOT NULL,
    [yaxis] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Team] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TeamLeft] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TeamRight] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UPPosition] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
    [sequence1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MaxSequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sequence2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DownPossession] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LeftSpace] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UPLeftSpace] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WEBTreeMap_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TopIDNO] ASC,
    [TopEda] ASC,
    [IDNO] ASC,
    [Eda] ASC,
    [Soshiki] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WEBTreeMap_2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_WEBTreeMap_2_SequenceNO]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SequenceNO]
;

DECLARE @IDNO varchar(10), @Eda varchar(3), @Seigenint int, @Soshiki varchar(1);
SELECT @IDNO = '0000000001', @Eda = '001', @Seigenint = 2000000, @Soshiki = '1';

UPDATE WEBTreeMap SET MapLimitLV_1 = 0 WHERE IDNO = @IDNO AND Eda = @Eda;   
delete WEBTreeMap_2 WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda and Soshiki = @Soshiki; 

DECLARE @LV int, @LVNinzu1LVMae int, @LVNinzu int;
SET @LV = 0;
SET @LVNinzu1LVMae = 0;
SET @LVNinzu = 0;



    /* set Top */
    INSERT INTO WEBTreeMap_2 (TopIDNO, TopEda, IDNO, Eda, Soshiki, LV, MapLimitFG, xaxis, yaxis, Team, TeamLeft, TeamRight, UPPosition, sequence1, MaxSequence, sequence2, SequenceNO, DownPossession, LeftSpace, UPLeftSpace)
    SELECT IDNO, Eda, IDNO, Eda, @Soshiki, @LV, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 AS TeamLeft, 0 AS TeamRight, '', 1, 1, 1, 1, DownPossession, 0, 0 FROM WEBTreeMap WHERE IDNO = @IDNO AND Eda = @Eda
    ;

    WHILE @LVNinzu <= @Seigenint
    BEGIN

        SELECT @LVNinzu = COUNT(*) FROM WEBTreeMap_2 WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki;

        print 'LV ： ' + convert(varchar,@LV)
        print '@LVNinzu ： ' + convert(varchar,@LVNinzu)
        print '@Seigenint ： ' + convert(varchar,@Seigenint)

        --UPDATE WEBTreeMap SET MapLimitLV_1 = @LV WHERE IDNO = @IDNO AND Eda = @Eda;

        IF @LVNinzu >= @Seigenint BEGIN BREAK END;

        SET @LV = @LV + 1;

        INSERT INTO WEBTreeMap_2 (TopIDNO, TopEda, IDNO, Eda, Soshiki, LV, MapLimitFG, xaxis, yaxis, Team, TeamLeft, TeamRight, UPPosition, sequence1, MaxSequence, sequence2, DownPossession, LeftSpace, UPLeftSpace)
        SELECT Jowy.TopIDNO, Jowy.TopEda, Kawy.IDNO, Kawy.Eda, @Soshiki, @LV,  Kawy.MapLimitFG_1, Jowy.xaxis/* + ((80 + 20) * LeftSpace) */ AS xaxis, Jowy.yaxis + 110 + 20 AS yaxis, Jowy.xaxis/* + ((80 + 20) * LeftSpace) */ AS Team, Jowy.xaxis/* + ((80 + 20) * LeftSpace) */ AS TeamLeft, Jowy.xaxis/* + ((80 + 20) * LeftSpace) */ AS TeamRight
        , (Jowy.IDNO + Jowy.Eda) AS UPPosition
        , (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Jowy.IDNO, Jowy.Eda ORDER BY Kawy.IDNO, Kawy.Eda)) AS ren1, 0 AS MaxSequence
        , (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Jowy.xaxis /* ,Jowy.IDNO, Jowy.Eda */, Kawy.IDNO, Kawy.Eda)) AS ren2, Kawy.DownPossession AS DownPossession, 0 AS LeftSpace, Jowy.LeftSpace AS UPLeftSpace
        FROM WEBTreeMap AS Kawy INNER JOIN WEBTreeMap_2 as Jowy ON Jowy.IDNO = Kawy.UPIDNO AND Jowy.Eda = Kawy.UPEda
        AND Jowy.TopIDNO = @IDNO AND Jowy.TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND Jowy.LV = @LV - 1 AND Jowy.MapLimitFG = 0
        ;

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN
                UPDATE WEBTreeMap SET MapLimitLV_1 = 100 WHERE IDNO = @IDNO AND Eda = @Eda; 
            BREAK

            END;

        WITH t1 AS (
            SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team, Max(sequence1) AS MaxRen
            FROM WEBTreeMap_2
            WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV
            GROUP BY TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team
        )
        UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET MaxSequence = MaxRen
        FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS w INNER JOIN t1 ON w.TopIDNO = t1.TopIDNO AND w.TopEda = t1.TopEda AND w.Soshiki = t1.Soshiki AND w.LV = t1.LV AND w.Team = t1.Team
        ;

        /* gather left */
        UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = Team + (((80 + 20) * ROUND((MaxSequence / 2),0)) * -1) + (CASE (MaxSequence % 2) WHEN 0 THEN + ((80 / 2) + (20 / 2)) ELSE 0 END)
        WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV AND MaxSequence > 1 /* AND sequence1 = 1 */
        ;
        /*
        SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team, (((80 + 20) * ROUND((MaxSequence / 2),0)) * -1) - (CASE (MaxSequence % 2) WHEN 0 THEN + ((80 / 2) + (20 / 2)) ELSE 0 END)
        FROM WEBTreeMap_2
        WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV AND sequence1 = 1
        */

        /* spread */
        UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET TeamLeft = xaxis, xaxis = xaxis + ((80 + 20) * (sequence1 - 1))
        WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV 
        ;

        WITH t1 AS (
            SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team, MAX(xaxis) AS MaxX
            FROM WEBTreeMap_2
            WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV 
            GROUP BY TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team
        )
        UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET TeamRight = MaxX
        FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS w INNER JOIN t1 ON w.TopIDNO = t1.TopIDNO AND w.TopEda = t1.TopEda AND w.Soshiki = t1.Soshiki AND w.LV = t1.LV AND w.Team = t1.Team
        /* WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV */
        ;

        /* move each team */

        IF object_id('tempdb..#Team') IS not NULL DROP TABLE #Team;
        SELECT * INTO #Team FROM (
            SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Team) AS TeamNO, Team, TeamLeft, TeamRight
            FROM WEBTreeMap_2
            WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV 
            GROUP BY TopIDNO, TopEda, Soshiki, LV, Team, TeamLeft, TeamRight
        ) AS t
        ;
        /*
        select * from #Team
        */

        DECLARE @MaxT int, @imaT int, @sa int, @TeamMei int;
        SELECT @imaT = 1, @MaxT = (SELECT MAX(TeamNO) FROM #Team), @TeamMei = 0
        ;

        WHILE @imaT <= @MaxT
        BEGIN 

            SET @sa = 0;

            SELECT @TeamMei = Team FROM #Team WHERE TeamNO = @imaT + 1;
            SELECT @sa = (((SELECT TeamRight FROM #Team WHERE TeamNO = @imaT) + (80 + 20)) - (SELECT TeamLeft FROM #Team WHERE TeamNO = @imaT + 1))

            IF @sa > 0
            BEGIN

                UPDATE #Team SET TeamLeft = TeamLeft + @sa, TeamRight = TeamRight + @sa WHERE TeamNO = @imaT + 1 /* TeamNO > @imaT */

                UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = xaxis + @sa, TeamLeft = TeamLeft + @sa, TeamRight = TeamRight + @sa
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2
                WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV AND Team = @TeamMei
                ;

            END;

            SELECT @imaT = @imaT + 1;

        END;    /* WHILE @imaT <= @MaxT */


        IF @LV >= 30 BREAK;

        SET @LVNinzu1LVMae = @LVNinzu;

        WITH R AS (
            SELECT * FROM WEBTreeMap_2  WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki AND LV = @LV
        )
        , Aki AS (
        SELECT R.IDNO, R.Eda, R.sequence2, MAX(L.sequence2) AS MaxRen 
        FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS L INNER JOIN R ON R.TopIDNO = L.TopIDNO AND R.TopEda = L.TopEda AND R.Soshiki = L.Soshiki AND R.LV = L.LV
        AND R.sequence2 > L.sequence2 AND L.DownPossession = 1
        GROUP BY R.IDNO, R.Eda, R.sequence2
        )
        UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET LeftSpace = (Aki.sequence2 - MaxRen) - 1
        FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS w INNER JOIN Aki ON w.TopIDNO = @IDNO AND w.TopEda = @Eda AND w.Soshiki = @Soshiki AND w.LV = @LV
        AND w.IDNO = Aki.IDNO AND w.Eda = Aki.Eda
        ;

    END;        /* WHILE @LVNinzu <= @Seigenint */

    UPDATE WEBTreeMap SET MapLimitLV_1 = @LV WHERE IDNO = @IDNO AND Eda = @Eda;

    DECLARE @CntUpdate int;
    SELECT @CntUpdate = 1;

        WHILE @CntUpdate > 0
        BEGIN

        print '@CntUpdate ： ' + convert(varchar,@CntUpdate)

        SELECT @CntUpdate = 0;

            /* UP is center of DOWNs */
            IF object_id('tempdb..#UPMoving') IS not NULL DROP TABLE #UPMoving;
            WITH t1 AS (
                SELECT xaxis + (80 / 2) AS LeftEnd, LEFT(UPPosition,10) AS UPID, RIGHT(UPPosition,3) AS UPEda
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2
                WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV AND */ AND sequence1 = 1
            ), t2 AS (
                SELECT xaxis + (80 / 2) AS RightEnd, LEFT(UPPosition,10) AS UPID, RIGHT(UPPosition,3) AS UPEda
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2
                WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* LV = @LV AND */ AND sequence1 = MaxSequence
            )
            SELECT * INTO #UPMoving FROM (
                SELECT t1.UPID, t1. UPEda, (((t2.RightEnd + t1.LeftEnd) / 2) - (80 / 2)) AS UPaxis
                --SELECT t1.UPID, t1. UPEda, (LeftEnd + (t2.RightEnd - t1.LeftEnd)) - (80 / 2) AS UPaxis
                FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.UPID = t2.UPID AND t1.UPEda = t2.UPEda
            ) AS oya
            ;
            /*
            select * from #UPMoving order by UPID
            */

            UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = UPaxis
            FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS Jowy INNER JOIN #UPMoving AS Kawy ON Jowy.IDNO = Kawy.UPID AND Jowy.Eda = Kawy.UPEda AND Jowy.xaxis < Kawy.UPaxis
            WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV */
            ;

            SELECT @CntUpdate = @CntUpdate + @@ROWCOUNT;

            SELECT @LV = @LV;
            WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN

                /* moving stray cats */
                WITH L AS (
                    SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, IDNO, Eda, Soshiki, LV, xaxis, Team, sequence2
                    FROM WEBTreeMap_2 
                    WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV - 1 */
                )
                UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = L.xaxis + (80 + 20)
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS R INNER JOIN L ON L.TopIDNO = R.TopIDNO AND L.TopEda = R.TopEda AND L.Soshiki = R.Soshiki AND L.LV = R.LV AND 
                R.sequence2 = L.sequence2 + 1 AND R.xaxis < L.xaxis + (80 + 20) /* AND DownPossession = 0 */
                ;

            --SELECT @CntUpdate = @CntUpdate + @@ROWCOUNT;      

            END;    /* WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 */

                /* moving DOWNs based on UP position */
                WITH Jowy AS (
                    SELECT (IDNO + Eda) AS uppos /*, UPPosition */, Jowy.xaxis, Jowy.xaxis - Kawy.UPaxis AS distance
                    FROM #UPMoving AS Kawy INNER JOIN WEBTreeMap_2 AS Jowy ON Jowy.IDNO = Kawy.UPID AND Jowy.Eda = Kawy.UPEda AND Jowy.xaxis > Kawy.UPaxis
                    WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV */
                )
                UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = Kawy.xaxis + distance
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS Kawy INNER JOIN Jowy ON Jowy.uppos = Kawy.UPPosition
                WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV */
                ;

            SELECT @CntUpdate = @CntUpdate + @@ROWCOUNT;

            SELECT @LV = @LV;
            WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
            BEGIN

                /* moving stray cats */
                WITH L AS (
                    SELECT TopIDNO, TopEda, IDNO, Eda, Soshiki, LV, xaxis, Team, sequence2
                    FROM WEBTreeMap_2 
                    WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki /* AND LV = @LV - 1 */
                )
                UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = L.xaxis + (80 + 20)
                FROM WEBTreeMap_2 AS R INNER JOIN L ON L.TopIDNO = R.TopIDNO AND L.TopEda = R.TopEda AND L.Soshiki = R.Soshiki AND L.LV = R.LV AND 
                R.sequence2 = L.sequence2 + 1 AND R.xaxis < L.xaxis + (80 + 20) /* AND DownPossession = 0 */
                ;

            --SELECT @CntUpdate = @CntUpdate + @@ROWCOUNT;      

            END;    /* WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 */

        END;    /* WHILE @CntUpdate > 0 */


    DECLARE @LeftMost int;
    SELECT @LeftMost = MIN(xaxis) FROM WEBTreeMap_2 WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki
    ;
    UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET xaxis = xaxis + (@LeftMost * -1) WHERE TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki
    ;
    UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET SequenceNO = 1 WHERE sequence1 = 1 AND TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki
    ;
    UPDATE WEBTreeMap_2 SET SequenceNO = 2 WHERE sequence1 = MaxSequence AND TopIDNO = @IDNO AND TopEda = @Eda AND Soshiki = @Soshiki
    ;

    SELECT * FROM WEBTreeMap_2
    ;

    /* end */
```

Comment: Have you attempted any SQL yet?

Comment: Which RDMS and version?

Comment: many times again and again and...

Comment: on sqlserver 2012. better to use oracle?

Comment: @miya I have a SQL Server process which will build a 200K hier in 7 seconds, I'm just struggling with the positioning

Comment: @John. Thank you for trying it. I'm NOT good at SQL.